# Best way to get individual days from a column, using LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have the following data in one MSSQL Table column

```
2011-06-20 11:53:32.000
2011-06-20 11:54:24.000
2011-06-20 11:55:45.000
2011-08-05 10:24:12.000
2011-08-05 10:25:28.000
2011-08-05 10:26:20.000
2011-08-05 10:27:12.000
2011-08-05 10:28:04.000
2011-08-05 10:28:55.000
```

Using LINQ, I would like to get the following data from the column

```
2011-06-20 
2011-08-05
```

So I can put into a List<>

What's the best way to do this?  I already have the context stuff setup, so I don't need details on that.  I just need an idea of the best "query" and logic I can use to get this data.  Thanks!

Comment: so you want to get distinct dates?

Comment: Had this been linq-to-objects, I might suggest `items.Select(item => item.DateProperty.Date).Distinct()`. If you want to move this over to the DB side, I'm not sure what you'd use, as I don't think `.Date` would translate. There is probably a Linq-to-EF (-Sql) helper function to use, however.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, there won't be perfect chronological dates,  It'll be random dates, and I want each date, only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for all of the Distinct dates in a range of DateTimes, the following will show examples to get what you need, given you already have them in a string or by querying your database:

**Example (with list of strings)**:

```
var list; //Contains your dates
var result = list.Select(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString()).Distinct();
```

**Example (from database table)**:

```
List<String> dates = (FROM d in datesTable
                      SELECT d.date.ToShortDateString()).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Console Example to demonstrate functionality:**

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
list.Add(DateTime.Parse("2011-06-20 11:53:32.000"));
list.Add(DateTime.Parse("2011-05-20 11:53:32.000"));
list.Add(DateTime.Parse("2011-05-20 11:44:32.000"));
list.Add(DateTime.Parse("2011-04-20 11:53:32.000"));

var result = list.Select(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString()).Distinct();

foreach (string date in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: I don't think the answer could have gotten more perfect than that.  Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from t in mydates select distinct ( t.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To select distinct dates into a list try this:

```
List<String> myDates = (from t in myTable
                        select t.myDate.ToShortDateString()
                       ).Distinct().ToList()
```